# Android Studio, Google Firebase, Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, firebase

I am using Android Studio 2.3 on a mac mini.

I began by opening a fresh project.

MainActivity is a loadingScreen

```
connect project to firebase using Firebase Assistant
Write to firebase
```

Everything works up to here.

Then I attempt to add a GoogleMaps Activity and the project no longer compiles. The error I am being shown is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

```
app build.gradle
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "us.n_e_ar.akita"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is the other gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versions of the Firebase and Google Play Services libraries must be identical.  You can either downgrade to 10.0.1:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

or upgrade to 10.2.1:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
```

While you updating, it's probably wise to use the latest constraint layout lib:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Thank You!!!!, I knew where the error was, but not exactly what had been auto-generated.  worked like a charm. probably saved me a week.